# How does inner function have access to number in decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I found this, and tried to learn decorators in Python. But I don't understand how `inner` function has access to num, whereas outer (`facto_decorator`) function doesn't have access to it.

```
memory = {}

def facto_decorator(func):

    def inner(num): #how this function know we are talking about which num

        if num not in memory:
            memory[num] = func(num)
            print('result saved in memory')
        else:
            print('returning result from saved memory')
        return memory[num]

    return inner

@facto_decorator
def facto(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return num * facto(num-1)

a=int(input("enter your number: "))
print(facto(a))
print(facto(a)) # directly coming from saved memory
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps to paste your code into a visulizer that you can step through like https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=display. Altough for learning decorators recursive functions are not a good way to learn the concept

Answer (score 1):

```py
@facto_decorator
def facto(num):
  xxx
```

means

```py
def _facto(num):
  xxx
facto = facto_decorator(_facto)
```

so

```py
facto(a)
```

means

```
def _facto(num):
  xxx
facto_decorator(_facto)(a)
```

means

```py
inner(a)
```